# Determine the GraphicsConfiguration of a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, multiple-monitors

I know I can display a `JFrame` on different monitors / `GraphicsConfiguration` / devices but what about doing the inverse: is it possible, from a `JFrame`'s reference, to find to which `GraphicsConfiguration` it is attached?

As a side-question: is it possible for me to start a `JFrame` by passing a specific `GraphicsConfiguration` and then have the user somehow move the `JFrame` to another `GraphicsConfiguration`? (if it's not possible for the user to do such a thing then I take it that I could just track to which `GraphicsConfiguration` I attach in the first place and so I can always find that information back anyway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following code to find which `GraphicsConfiguration` is used:

```
frame.getGraphicsConfiguration();
```

To set your `GraphicsConfiguration` you can use `Frame f= new JFrame(gc);`